# How to find a primitivefunction for $(\sec(x))^3$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I had a test where I was asked this question. I integrated the function by taking $\tan x=u$ and then $\sec^2x \, dx=du$. I took $\sec(x) =\sqrt{1+u^2}$ and then using the basic formulas calculated the correct answer but my teacher didn't give me marks for my solution. Please  explain me why. He gave me a zero.I can't post pictures otherwise I would have shown you

I got the answer $(\tan x\sec x-\log(\tan x+\sec x)/2$

Here the picture of my solution https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E9e1JoX_8C28h7k8uW6bBpoYZFy1LuCM/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Can you please write the exact steps you did in your question? This will help me understand where you could improve. Also, what do you mean by 'my teacher didn't give me marks'? Did he not give you **any** marks?

Comment: Correct answer and no marks ? How come ?

Comment: I think you should ask your teacher.

Comment: @ChandaBagri I understand that you can't take pictures during an exam, but can you please write down what you can remember? Show some effort, otherwise others won't show effort as well by writing an answer.

Comment: I have my exam paper he gave me the paper back but didn't told me my mistake.

Comment: @ChandaBagri : A grammatical point: The negation of "He gave" is "He didn't give", not "He didn't gave", and the negation of "He told" is "He didn't tell", not "He didn't told".

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int\sec^3x\,dx 
&= \int\dfrac{1}{\cos^3x}\,dx \\
&= \int\dfrac{\cos x}{(1-\sin^2x)^2}\,dx \hspace{0.5cm};\hspace{0.5cm} \sin x=u\\
&= \int\dfrac{1}{(1-u^2)^2}\,dx \\
&= \dfrac{u}{2(1-u^2)}+\dfrac{1}{4}\ln\dfrac{1+u}{1-u}+C\\
&= \dfrac{u}{2(1-u^2)}+\dfrac{1}{4}\ln\dfrac{1+u}{1-u}+C\\
&= \dfrac{\sin x}{2\cos^2x}+\dfrac{1}{4}\ln\dfrac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}+C
\end{align}

Comment: An answer is more than a list of steps. It would help the OP more if you described *why* you multiplied top and bottom by $\cos x$ in line $2$, and how you got from line $3$ to line $4$.

Comment: There are many details here, so we leave them to OP!

Comment: But how did you go from line $4$ to line $5$ ? ;-)

Comment: Hard copied!...

Comment: @MyGlasses Of course I am not in favor of doing the OP's homework step by step, but just one or two lines to annotate this would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:
\begin{align}
\int \sec^3 x \, dx = {} & \int (\sec x) \Big( \sec^2 x \, dx\Big) = \overbrace{\int u\, dv = uv - \int v \, du}^{\text{integration by parts}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \sec x \tan x - \int (\tan x) \big( \sec x\tan x\, dx\big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \sec x \tan x - \int(\sec x)(\tan^2 x) \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \sec x \tan x - \int(\sec x) (\sec^2 x - 1) \,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \sec x\tan x + \int \sec x\,dx - \int\sec^3 x\,dx. \\[10pt]
& \text{Then adding $\int\sec^3 x\,dx$ to both sides, we get} \\[10pt]
2\int\sec^3 x\, dx & = \sec x \tan x + \int \sec x\, dx. \\[10pt]
& \text{Hence} \\[10pt]
\int \sec^3 x\, dx & = \frac 1 2 \sec x \tan x + \frac 1 2 \int \sec x\, dx = \cdots
\end{align}